# SQL like '%term%' except without letters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, wildcard, sql-like

I'm searching against a table of news articles. The 2 relevant columns are `ArticleTitle` and `ArticleText`. When I want to search an article for a particular term, i started out with

`column LIKE '%term%'`.

However that gave me a  lot of articles with the term inside anchor links, for example `<a href="example.com/*term*>` which would potentially return an irrelevant article.

So then I switched to

`column LIKE '% term %'`.

The problem with this query is it didn't find articles who's title or text began/ended with the term. Also it didn't match against things like `term-` or `term's`, which I do want.

It seems like the query i want should be able to do something like this

```
'%[^a-z]term[^a-z]%
```

This should exclude terms within anchor links, but everything else. I think this query still excludes strings that begin/end with the term. Is there a better solution? Does SQL-Server's FULL TEXT INDEXING solve this problem?

Additionally, would it be a good idea to store `ArticleTitle` and `ArticleText` as HTML-free columns? Then i could use `'%term%'` without getting anchor links. These would be 2 extra columns though, because eventually i will need the original HTML for formatting purposes.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea because you need to query those fields

Comment: Using % wildcards to search text fields is horribly slow and fraught with trouble like this. Create a full-text index and use a [CONTAINS()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server's `LIKE` allows you to define Regex-like patterns like you described.

A better option is to use [fulltext search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx):

```
WHERE CONTAINS(ArticleTitle, 'term')
```

exploits the index properly (the `LIKE '%term%'` query is slow), and provides other benefit in the search algorithm.

Additionally, you might benefit from storing a plaintext version of the article alongside the HTML version, and run your search queries on it.

Comment: For the plaintext, if you never need to search only Title or Text, but always want to search both, then strip Title and Text of HTML and concatenate them into a single plaintext value for full text search. That'll provide better performance than saying `CONTAINS(PlainTitle, 'term') OR CONTAINS(PlainText, 'term')`.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is not designed to interpret HTML strings. As such, you'd only be able to postpone the problem till a more difficult issue arrives (for example, a comment node that contains your search terms as part of a plain sentence).

You can still utilize FULL TEXT as a prefilter and then run an HTML analysis on the application layer to further filter your result set.